# Warum schreibt man «gescheit» mit T?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, spelling

Warum schreibt man «gescheit» mit T? Das Wort kommt ja von «scheiden» (bedeutet also das Vermögen, gut zu unter-«scheiden»), so dass eigentlich die Schreibung «gescheid» vorzuziehen wäre – wie Grimm es auch tut (vgl. [DWB: «gescheid»](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=gescheid)).

Auch ist in schweizerdeutschen Dialekten, wo der Gegensatz zwischen D und T nicht durch Konsonantenschwächung, Auslautverhärtung und aufgepfropftes niederdeutsches Lautsystem verundeutlicht worden ist, die Aussprache zweifelsfrei mit D («gschiid», «gschiider»).

Comment: Was das DWB selber dazu schreibt, ist nicht genug?

Comment: Aus Deinem eigenen Link: _seit dem 17. jahrh. aus falscher ableitung gescheut geschrieben und noch bis heute gesprochen_

Comment: Das Wort *gescheit* ist übrigens nicht nur mit *entscheiden, scheiden, die Scheide, die Scheidung* usw. verwandt, sondern auch mit *das Scheit, scheitern, der Scheitel, scheißen, die Schiene, der Schi.* Auch die englischen Wörter *shit* und *science* sowie die aus dem altgriechischen importierten Wörter *Schizophrenie* und *Schisma* haben alle dieselbe urindoeuropäische Wurzel.

Comment: Vlt. kan man als Kompromis sagen, -d't wäre die *richtige* Form, nur unterschiedlige entstellt worden--aber wie kämme ich dazu?!?  Bemerkennswert: Phonem-Länge, im Mittelhochdeutschen noch teils "contrastive", endwiegelte sich unterschiedlig in die Dialekte. Im Auslaut im Mitel Barrierischen (bis hoch zu Wien) ging er Kontrast wege, weil "predictable". Das würgte, glaub ich, auf fortis-/lenis-Konsonanten. Genua kan ich das aber nie widergeben, insoweit also nicht einschaetzen, ob's everhaubt relevant ist. Vgl vlt *Stadt, Staat, Stätte / Stad'l*. Ansonstonsen was Hubertus sagt, vgl *schei-tel*.

Comment: Sorry, siehe GUIDO SEILER,
On the Development of the Bavarian Ouantity System: "The morphonological alternations discussed in (20) above provide a sali-ent pattern for the distribution of lengthened and short vowels: vowels are lengthened before singletons, and they are short before geminates." (p. 118) "However, only Middle Bavarian generalized that not only most but
*all* long surface vowels are lengthened vowels." (p. 119), (20d) sg. [flu:s] ~ pl. [fliss] 'river'". Wegen apocope wie in *flyss(e)* wäre *g'scheid'* ~ der *g'schadd' Bub'* zu erwarten. Wenn dem nicht so ist, dann wegn cluster

Comment: *Scheiße* hängt ja wohl auch mit *ausscheiden* zusammen, trotzdem schreibt man es nicht *scheide*, so zu sagen. Die Ausgangssituation dieser Frage ist schon zum *scheitern* verurteilt, denn in Norddeutschen Dialekten mit Auslautverhärtung besteht kein signifikanter Unterschied. Man sieht, hier wurden weder Kosten noch Mühen gescheidt.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Wechsel zwischen D und T, vor allem im Auslaut, ist recht häufig und nicht ungewöhnlich.

Das Geld (mit **d**) ist ja auch mit *vergelten, gelten, Entgelt* (alle  mit **t**) verwandt.

Auch das *Brot* (heute mit **t**) wurde früher zumindest in Österreich *»Brod«* (mit **d**) geschrieben. Der Familienname *Brodschneider* erinnert noch daran, und ich kann mich erinnern, dass es in den 1980er-Jahren im Grazer Univiertel noch eine uralte Bäckerei gab, wo über dem Eingang *»Brod und Semmeln«* stand.

Comment: Erich Kästners schreibt irgendwo (ich meine, es sei in seiner Teil-Autobiographie *Als ich ein kleiner Junge war* gewesen): »Mein Vater schrieb noch ›Brod‹ und ›Thür‹.« Kästner wurde in Dresden geboren, sein Vater hat vor der Rechtschreibreform von 1901 das Schreiben gelernt.

Comment: wegen *Gold*, der Baltich-Germanischen Isoglosse, ist Geld ~ gelten jetzt nicht unbedingt der beste Vergleich.